# How do I display an image in a plot using Python?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I imported matplotlib.pyplot and also NumPy

I wanted to display an image from my desktop to the plot but I get a `TypeError`.

code :

```
img = (image) ( here do we need to give the location of the file or the file directly)

imshow(img, extent=[-25,25,-25,25], cmap = cm.bone)
colorbar()


Error: TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

I am using Pycharm as my ide.

Comment: I removed the matlab tag, since your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with matlab. Also, take a look at `imread`.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks Andras and avstenit, it did work with "imread". cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

You are a bit ambiguous about

> here do we need to give the location of the file or the file directly

No you don't. You need to use some imaging library to read an image. `img="C:\image.jpg"` does not read an image!

For example, to read a 'png' image, you could:

```
# Copypaste from docs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
img=mpimg.imread('myimage.png')
# end
# from now on you can use img as an image, but make sure you know what you are doing!
imgplot=plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Read more at [Image tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) at matplotlib's doc

Comment: Note that I don't think you actually need to `import numpy` for this, and I have a hunch that `imread` and `imshow` are already in `matplotlib.pyplot`. (But you need `mpimg.imshow` otherwise.)

Comment: @moooeeeep probably yeah. First 4 lines are a copy paste from the docs,  next line a copypaste from the OP. I guess errors are in the OPs line.

Answer (score 0):

Is `img` a **numpy array** of the right type?

If you read the image using pillow,etc. and have an Image object you have to get the numpy array from it ( `img.getdata()` )

> X : array_like, shape (n, m) or (n, m, 3) or (n, m, 4)
>
> Display the image in X to current axes. X may be a float array, a
>   uint8 array or a PIL image. If X is an array, it can have the
>   following shapes:
>
> MxN – luminance (grayscale, **float array only**) MxNx3 – RGB (**float or
>   uint8 array**) MxNx4 – RGBA (**float or uint8 array**)
>   The value for each component of **MxNx3 and MxNx4 float arrays should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0**;

Either normalize img so it's between 0.0 and 1.0 or convert it to uint8 (  `img=np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)` ).

Comment: yes it gave me an Value error when i used a JPG file, it tells me to use pillow for handling different type of files. It gives me a suggestion to use only PNG